# Efficient scheduling of multiple people and locations

Tags: python

I am attempting to create a program to schedule asynchronous carpool scheduling. For example, given a single long street represented by this line:

A----------------------B---------------------------C-------------------------D

If Alice, Bob, and Chad all need to be at point D at the same, and start from points A,B,and C respectively, but Bob doesn't have a car, the program needs to output that the best solution is for Alice to pick Bob up. If the Google maps API is used to determine distance and time between two points (precision may be approximate), what is the best way to determine the most efficient set of actions?

In this simplified scenario, there is a rather limited number of possibilities, (Alice picks Bob up, Chad picks Bob up, Bob walks) and it is fairly simple to iterate and evaluate them based off of time or distance traveled, but when the number of possibilities numbers in the thousands or the millions, that approach doesn't scale well. I have been working for months trying to develop a more sophisticated algorithm, but due to my limited knowledge I have not been very successful

Comment: @RNar as I said, I tried an exhaustive iterative approach, but it doesn't scale well at all and burns up a ton of memory, I would like some input on some better solutions.

Comment: i just wanted you to expand on that, like how it was done. did you push every single path into a list and iterate to find the shortest, did you set everything into a graph, etc. the more info that you give, the better people will be suited to help you :)

Comment: on another note, graph theory is often the best way to approach problems like this. setting up a graph with vertices as geographical points and edges as the time it takes depending on transport would be ONE way to set it up but im not one to ask on well made algorithms

Comment: @RNar, You are correct in how I did it, but my exact methodology is not terribly relevant as the brute force iterative approach is by far the worst possible solution

Comment: in that case, yeah, look into graph theory. things like djikstra's algorithm are well known for find shortest paths. again, i would love to help you out more but im not that well versed in in and how to implement graph theory algorithms

Comment: @RNar Thanks, a starting point is good enough

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to generalize the problem, here's how I understand it:

*Given a graph G that describes connections between locations `L={l_0, ..., l_n}` on a map, and a set of participants `P = {p_0, ..., p_n}` find the best itinerary `I={l_s, ..., l_d}` for each participant to travel from their respective source location `l_s` to a common destination `l_d` such that all participants reach the destination independent of their means of travel. Some participants may need to take a detour to pick up other participants, in which case we want to find the solution with the lowest total cost (as in travel time required)*

Here's a rough sketch of how I would attempt to solve this problem:

1. build a graph of all nodes and how they are connected (e.g. in your example the graph is `G = [(A,B),(B,C),(C,D)]`).
2. add a weight to each edge which describes say its distance in some normalized way (metric, constant speed/time, ...)
3. for each participant specify the maximum speed available to them depending on the mode they can travel with (e.g. car, bike, walk).
4. for the participants with car (A,C) calculate the actual time it takes for each to reach the target destination from their respective source locations, using a shortest path algorithm such as [A* (a star)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm). This is actually a two-step process, step 1: calculate the shortest path, step 2: calculate the time it takes to travel each edge.

Google's map API would probably already provide all or most of the data you need to do these calculations (or even do the calculations for you).

As a result you get the best itinerary for each participant. Now we have to consider participants without car (here, B). For that we have to find the participant to take a detour such that the detour incurs the lowest cost. Thus,

5. calculate for each of of A,C two shortest path routes, i.e. step 1: source location => detour location (B), step 2: detour location (B) => destination location (D)
6. select the best option, i.e. minimize for total travel time

Since you tagged this as a Python question, you may want to check out [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/) or [graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/) to implement.

Disclaimer: Obviously this leaves out quite a lot of details, and may even be completely off. Feedback appreciated. To [paraphrase Donald Knuth](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?DonKnuth), I only thought about this, I didn't implement or test it.

Comment: You correctly understood the question, this information is quite valuable. Though I'm having trouble understanding step 5, specifically the first clause "Calculate for each of A,C a two-step shortest path route,"

Comment: @ChuckFulminata updated step 5, hope it is clear now